# How to use another state within a setState hook in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to set the state of a variable within another `setState` function.

I have code that's something like this:

```
const [songs, setSongs] = useState()
const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState()

function async firstClick() {
  
  function secondClick() {
     songs = await fetch("/songs")
     setSongs(songs)
  }
  
  setPlaylists(
    <>
      // other element that have trigger handleClick() on click
      {songs}
    </>
  );
}
```

The process is:

1. A user clicks on an element which triggers `firstClick()`.
2. `setPlaylists()` sets `playlists`.
3. A user clicks on an element that was was set from `setPlaylists()` which triggers `secondClick()`.
4. `secondClick()` sets `songs`.
5. `songs` in `playlists` is not updated because the state has already been updated.

Is there a React pattern for this situation? How can I set state of `songs` and have it update within the state of `setPlaylists()`.

Comment: Actually it is not so clear what exactly you are trying to do here. Can you elaborate and be clear so that people can help you?

Comment: use useEffectHook or useCallback hook

Comment: you can use useMemo Hook as well

Comment: just to clarify before trying to answer, why `secondclick()` is contained in `firstclick()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const updatedSongs = async () => {
songs = await fetch("/songs")
     setSongs(songs)
}

function handleClick() {
     updatedSongs()
  }


useEffect(() => { updatedSongs() },[])
```

Comment: Where is `setPlaylist()` used though?